# Cocoa Question: How do I get a string representation of a SEL?

Tags: cocoa, css-selectors, introspection

Is it possible, given a `SEL` to generate a string representation of the method it refers to?

For context:

I have an object instance initialized thusly:

```
-(id) initWithTarget:(id)object action: (SEL)action;
```

Within the instance I would like to echo the string name of the method referred to by `SEL`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NSStringFromSelector](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector)

Conversion in opposite direction is also possible

[NSSelectorFromString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sel_getName`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/sel_getName).